# React Navigation - default goBack button not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I created simple `StackNavigator`

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator({
    Conversations: {screen: ConversationsContainer},
    Chat: {screen: Chat}
}, {
    navigationOptions: {
        headerTintColor: "#36c3e7"
    },
})
```

and when I navigate from conversations to chat and I tried to press go back button then application crashed with error `_this.props.navigation.goBack is not a function` but when I use back gesture on iOS simulator it works.

Comment: Post the part of the code where `goBack` is called

Comment: I don't know where goBack is called. I sad. Go back button is default and I didn't change anything

Comment: StackNavigator deprecated check https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

Answer (score 1):

With my case I had this issue with `react-native-navigation v5`. To fix this I did this:

1. I've added the following on android/app/build.gradle under dependencies

   `implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-rc01"
   implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0-alpha02"`
2. wiped the emulator by `emulator -avd <device_name> -wipe-data`
3. `cd android` && `gradle clean`
4. `react-native run-android`